# Make one Bamboo plan cause other plan to be scheduled with delay

Tags: automation, delay, schedule, bamboo, cicd

I have a number of multi-part tests that require me to run a setup phase first, then wait about 30 minutes before I can run the verification phase. I'm limited to a single agent, so including the delay in the test itself is very undesirable as it ties up the CI/CD system.

What I would like to do is have the setup plan, when complete, cause the corresponding verification plan to be scheduled 30 minutes later.

I know you can have one plan trigger another plan, but that's not quite what I want as that will happen immediately after the first plan, which won't work.

What's the best way to do this with Bamboo or is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Unless you delay the job programatically from a script task which, as you mention, is not ideal for your use case.